# Why do termite pellets fall in a perfect circle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, probability, randomness

I was just wondering why termite pellets fall down from my bed in a perfect circle.

You can see from the images that the follow down on the floor making a perfect geometric figure which is void in the middle.

Is it just falling down and rolling randomly or does it have something to do with quantum mechanics?

Images And Videos [Here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwuPbMDI0GOrQlRER3J4TGZqYjQ&usp=drive_web&ddrp=1#)

[ This is not a single occurrence and these circles comes up very often under some of our old beds. ]

The closest answer I could think of is, the pellets falls down in about 2 inch diameter right below the hole, bounces up and move outwards. But why it is not filling up the inside of the circle?

Comment: are these pellets made by termites in the bed or have they been put down to kill termites?

Comment: This is appropriate for an entomology site. One has to study the way the termite eats , if it is the left overs of making a hole, or it defecates, if it is that. No, it is not quantum mechanics other than everything at the bottom is quantum mechanics. ( it is not my -1 but I fear you will get more as the question is not suitable here).

Comment: Okay, I must admit I thought this was a hokey question when I first read it.  But the photos are intriguing.  The only thing I can think of is the dust (or whatever is being dropped) has a slight electrical charge that causes particles to repel each other as they fall.  But that sounds pretty far-fetched.  I'm looking forward to seing what people come up with.

Comment: @adziggy . Thanks for the response. My question is not actually about termites. Why would small balls falling down spread themselves in a circle. Why cant they just pile up in the centre.

Comment: You have to give more information. Were exactly are the termites? Have you seen this effect more times? How long did it take? Did you see the termites dropping? Is there any circular object on the wood? You could post a photo of the bed from below.

Comment: @jinawee, I have added a video. Yes this happens very often and is very common in our location. This one should have taken about 3-4 days.

Comment: The closest answer I could think of is, the pellets falls down in about 2 inch diameter right below the hole,  bounces up and move outwards. But why it is not filling up the inside of the circle?

Comment: I think that the best answer would be to make a video/time-lapse of the circle formation. Btw, shouldn't you get them killed?

Comment: Hi ibsenv. Linking to private clouds, dropbox, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/2451) meta post.

Answer (score 2):

I have to admire the fact that in the face of an infestation like this you wonder about the physics instead of setting the bed on fire to kill the termites...

Looking at the video it seems to me that the pellets are not "dropped" but "ejected". If that is the case, then if the termites exit hole is slightly angled, they will eject their pellet not straight down but with some lateral momentum.

If you are willing to concede that your bed is a goner you could do the experiment of placing it on a set of raised blocks. If my theory is right the circle would get larger - roughly with the square root of the height. Similarly if you placed a shoe box or something under the hole to catch the droppings they would make a smaller ring.

In the name of science go ahead and do the experiment. In the name of common sense, get an exterminator!

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Termite pellets are the feces of a termite, the left overs of its eating wood and in no way of the size shown by the size of the bed.

The pellets are from a [colony of insects](http://brookerpestcontrol.com/bug/drywood-termite/).

> Often, the only obvious signs of infestation are little mounds of fecal pellets building up underneath the infested wood or the appearance of “kick-out” holes in the surface of the wood. Drywood termites make tiny holes in the surface of the wood that allow them to expel their fecal pellets.

If one looks at the [gallery for termite pellets](https://www.google.gr/search?q=termite%20pellets&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&imgil=BS3-xRfxJEfJXM%253A%253BZec8E6x9A8v3QM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fbrookerpestcontrol.com%25252Fbug%25252Fdrywood-termite%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=BS3-xRfxJEfJXM%253A%252CZec8E6x9A8v3QM%252C_&usg=__yIP3Dm-NsKw5BJGGTxz6JeN3N54%3D&biw=1366&bih=657&ved=0CDIQyjc&ei=_YQzVZHgL5Xfap3IgdgP#imgrc=BS3-xRfxJEfJXM%253A%3BZec8E6x9A8v3QM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fbrookerpestcontrol.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2013%252F06%252Ftermite-drywood-pellets.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fbrookerpestcontrol.com%252Fbug%252Fdrywood-termite%252F%3B940%3B588) none look like a nice circle. What probably has happened, the colony is around a hard knob of wood they could not eat their way through, and they made tiny holes all around. The width is due both to the width of the ring around the knob and the momentum of ejection of the pellet by each of the termite insects.

You should turn   the bed over and look for the tiny holes around a thick knot.

Edit after editing of question and addition of video.:

The video looks like housecleaning, i.e. not termites defecating sequentially in a queue, but like a sweeping cleanup of a pile ( like the ones shown in the gallery I linked). Ants do that, one finds little mountains of earth in spring outside their nests.

The center not filling up would be momentum conservation. When one sweeps, lateral momentum is given to the debris, so it will not fall straight down. In a sense the empty center is the image of the hole, its width dependent on how much lateral impulse the ants can impart.

One could check whether the hole is charged all around . This might happen [triboelectrically.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect), the ants by pushing the pellets charging them opposite to the wood.  Then extra lateral impulse could be imparted to the pellets depending on the angles of exit.

Nothing to do with quantum mechanics (except that  all nature basically is quantum mechanical).

Comment: No anna, there was not hard knob in the wood.  Its just a tiny hole. Also this is not a single occurrence of this. This is very common in our place is ignored by everybody. I have added a video please check

Comment: I have edited the answer